# Ajax - send array of objects using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am constructing an array of objects from form data in order to send to a processing script that will then send the data on to an API. The API does not allow CORS ajax requests, hence the need to send to an external script first.

I can return simple strings, but when I stringify the data I have, the response from the server is always that the POST or GET (have tried both) data is just an empty array.

**JS**

```
$('#enrol').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var collection = [];

    $('#enrol .form-row').each(function() {
        var email = $(this).find('input[type="email"]').val();
        var c1Val = $(this).find('.c1').is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false';
        var c2Val = $(this).find('.c2').is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false';
        var c3Val = $(this).find('.c3').is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false';
        var c4Val = $(this).find('.c4').is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false';
        var c5Val = $(this).find('.c5').is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false';
        var c6Val = $(this).find('.c6').is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false';
        var c7Val = $(this).find('.c7').is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false';

        var person = {
            'email'   : email,
            'course1' : c1Val,
            'course2' : c2Val,
            'course3' : c3Val,
            'course4' : c4Val,
            'course5' : c5Val,
            'course6' : c6Val,
            'course7' : c7Val,
        }
        collection.push(person);

    });

    var dataString = JSON.stringify(collection);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/script.php',
        data: dataString,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
})
```

**PHP**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: URLHERE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

var_dump($_GET);
```

What I don't get is if I just JSON.stringify a simple string, I get the data returned, yet the array of objects seems to arrive at the php script as an empty array - or at least that's what the console.log is suggesting. I've outputted the dataString variable to ensure it has data - it does.

Comment: What __I__ don't get is what is the problem?

Comment: This bit - "I can return simple strings, but when I stringify the data I have, the response from the server is always that the POST or GET (have tried both) data is just an empty array."

Comment: Did you try `data: {mydata: collection},` without the stringify

Comment: @RiggsFolly this worked (with the stringify) - stupid as that's how I have always structured it before! If you chuck that in an answer with an explanation I'll mark as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a simple one, I wasn't providing a key for the post array -

```
data: dataString
```

should have been

```
data: { data: dataString }
```

Then the output of `var_dump($_GET['data'))` contained the data I was sending.

Answer (score 1):

i have something similar in my own project.
This works for me:

```
jsonObj = new Object();
jsonObj['email'] = email;
jsonObj['course1'] = c1Val;
.
.
.

 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://www.example.com/script.php',
            data: {"data": JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},
            dataType:'JSON',
            cache: false,
.
.
.
});
```

**PHP:**

```
var_dump($_REQUEST['data']);
```

Comment: `dataType` argument doesn't do anything in this context. It's to tell jQuery what type of data the server will return; it doesn't change anything to how the data is sent by jQuery or received by PHP.  This works for you because by using `{"data": JSON.stringify(jsonObj)}`, you are no longer sending JSON, but a query string. If you Open the browser console to see what is sent to the server you will see something like `data="<json-string>"` which is not JSON structure

Comment: @BeetleJuice .. Yeah you are right about the dataType argument - useless in this context. 
But the problem should still be fixed like this...inside it's still JSON --> $_REQUEST['data'] is valid json and can be decoded and further processed.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will not automatically fill the superglobals `$_GET` and `$_POST` when the data arrives in JSON format. You'll need to do two things on the PHP side:

1. Manually capture the input
2. JSON-decode it into a PHP data structure

   ```
   // capture your raw JSON
   $datastring = file_get_contents("php://input");
   // decode it into a PHP array
   $collectionArray = json_decode($datastring, true);
   ```

On the jQuery side, the following may not be needed, but I would be explicit about the type of content sent to the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/script.php',
    data: dataString,
    contentType : "application/json",
    ...
```